# Sound through headphone jack is tinny and distorted

Tags: sound, audio

I have a system76 Lemur pro and really hoping to move to elementary os, especially as Odin comes out on the stable branch. There is one hiccup. Sound behaves as expected through Bluetooth headphones, HDMI, and computer speakers. As soon as I plug in headphones sound is tinny and distorted. It is unusable for me.

Some things I've tried:

-I've installed pulse effects and pulseaudio switched back and forth on the audio streams

-I checked Alsamixer to see if something changes when headphones are plugged in. Played around with various sound levels

-Messed around with overamplification

-Unplugged / replugged

I can confirm this is repeatable. I've reinstalled elementary, getting the same result. I've tried the Odin daily build getting the same result. No other os I have tried behaves this way.

Let me know if you have any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arch Linux Wiki mentions this issue on the [Lemur Pro page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System76_Lemur_Pro).
Try creating the file `/etc/modprobe.d/headset.conf` with the line `options snd_hda_intel model=headset-mode-no-hp-mic`.
Then reboot the system.

Comment: Aha! I would not have assumed it was an issue with the lemur. I will test when I can.